# basic calculator not working because of the JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a basic calculator but my code doesn't add up. What my calculator is supposed to do is to add, subtract, divide or multiply the two numbers inserted in the inputs num1 and num2. Then print the answer in the empty div with answer as an id.

```js
var numbers = new Object();
numbers.num1 = -1;
numbers.num2 = -1;

$("#num1").bind("keyup mouseup", function() {
  numbers.num1 = ("#num1").val();

});

$("num1").bind("keyup mouseup", function() {
  numbers.num2 = ("num2").val();
});

$("#add").on("click", function() {
  var add = numbers.num1 + numbers.num2;
  $("#answer").text(add);
});

$("#substract").on("click", function() {
  var subs = numbers.num1 - numbers.num2;
  $("#answer").text(subs);
});

$("#multiply").on("click", function() {
  var multi = numbers.num1 * numbers.num2;
  $("#answer").text(multi);
});

$("#divide").on("click", function() {
  var div = numbers.num1 / numbers.num2;
  $("#answer").text(div)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-inputs">
  <form>
    <input type="number" name="inputNum1" id="num1">
  </form>
  <form>
    <input type="number" name="inputNum2" id="num2">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="functions">
  <button id="add">add</button>
  <button id="substract">substract</button>
  <button id="multiply">multiply</button>
  <button id="divide">divide</button>
</div>

<h2 id="answer"></h2>
```

Comment: What's not working in your code?

Comment: the buttons add, substract, divide and multiply don't seem to do anything

Comment: You have a typo in the second binding.  Is this for num2, #num2, ???

Comment: My hunch is you are getting string concatenation instead of numeral addition.  The jQuery `.val()` usually returns a string so you need to cast it to an in/float/whatever.  The cheap (but sometimes not recommended) way to do it is just `$(...).val()*1.0`.  Also, you are missing a few `$` in front of `("#num1").val();` and `("#num2").val();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some mistakes in your code. For instance,

```
numbers.num2 = ("num2").val();
```

is wrong because you have to use `$` sign in order to access a jquery object.

```
numbers.num2 = $("num2").val();
```

Also, `sum` of the numbers is the concatenation of the numbers because you forgot to convert to number using `parseInt()` function or using other methods.

```js
var numbers = new Object();
    numbers.num1 = -1;
    numbers.num2 = -1;

$("#num1").bind("keyup mouseup", function(){
    numbers.num1 = $("#num1").val();

});

$("#num2").bind("keyup mouseup",  function(){
    numbers.num2 = $("#num2").val();
});

$("#add").on("click", function(){
    var add = +numbers.num1 +(+ numbers.num2);
    $("#answer").text(add);
});

$("#substract").on("click", function(){
    var subs = numbers.num1 - numbers.num2;
    $("#answer").text(subs);
});

$("#multiply").on("click", function(){
    var multi = numbers.num1 * numbers.num2;
    $("#answer").text(multi);
});

$("#divide").on("click", function(){
    var div = numbers.num1/numbers.num2;
    $("#answer").text(div)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-inputs">
    <form>
        <input type="number" name="inputNum1" id="num1">
    </form>
    <form>
        <input type="number" name="inputNum2" id="num2">
    </form>
</div>
<div class = "functions">
<button id="add">add</button>
<button id="substract">substract</button>
<button id="multiply">multiply</button>
<button id="divide">divide</button>
</div>

<h2 id="answer"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's also the `#` symbol that he forgot to add before the `num2`. :)

Comment: @Catalyst, yes,i forgot about it to include in my post. Btw, +1 for your answer.

Comment: You too, mate :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You are missing the jQuery's `$`, and missing `#` in the element selector.

   ```
   $("#num1").bind("keyup mouseup", function(){
       numbers.num1 = $("#num1").val();

   });

   $("#num2").bind("keyup mouseup",  function(){
       numbers.num2 = $("#num2").val();
   });
   ```
2. You didn't convert the numbers to a number. Input values are treated as strings, so you need to convert them to a number so that JavaScript will calculate them correctly:

   ```
   $("#num1").bind("keyup mouseup", function(){
       numbers.num1 = parseInt($("#num1").val(), 10);

   });

   $("#num2").bind("keyup mouseup",  function(){
       numbers.num2 = parseInt($("#num2").val(), 10);
   });
   ```

(the second argument of the `parseInt` function is the radix, which is 10 in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the $ sign in these lines and # in the last one

```
$("#num1").bind("keyup mouseup", function(){
    numbers.num1 = $("#num1").val();

});

$("#num1").bind("keyup mouseup",  function(){
    numbers.num2 = $("#num2").val();
});
```